# Sorting on Kendo UI MVC Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing with Kendo UI Grid with MVC 5.  I am finding that I cannot appear to get the sorting working on my columns - I have read the Thread here - http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-sorting-filtering---doesn-t-work  but looking at my Bundle configs it looks like I have the correct js files included and looking at the Network in F12 as well it looks like they have been included.  I am using Bootstrap as well in my site - is there possibly something else needed to be included?

Bundle configs are as below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));
```

In my _Layout.cshtml I have the following in the  section

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
```

After @RenderBody() in _Layout.cshtml I have the includes for bootstrap

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/initialize")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

The folllowing shows the config of my Grid

```
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Car.Web.Models.CarViewModel>()
                          .Name("CarView")
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(180);
                              columns.Bound(c => c.ModelNo).Width(280);
                              columns.Bound(c => c.Colour).Width(120);
                              columns.Bound(c => c.FuelType).Width(65);
                          })
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 420px;" })
                        .Scrollable()
                        .Sortable(sortable => sortable
                            .AllowUnsort(true)
                            .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                        .PageSizes(true)
                        .ButtonCount(5))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetCarById", "api/Car"))
                        )
                )
```

Note I am using WebAPI controller - the CarController in my API folder looks like below:

```
    public DataSourceResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        //note stubbed data 1 will need to be passed in as id
        return GetCarById(1).ToDataSourceResult(request);
    }


    public IEnumerable<CarViewModel> GetCarById(int carId)
    {
        // call to service layer to get data
        var carResponse = _carService.GetCarDataById(carId);


        // map responses to grid

        return MapCarSelectView(carResponse );
    }

    private static IEnumerable<CarViewModel> MapCarSelectView(IEnumerable<CarResponse> carResponses)
    {
        return carResponses.Select(carResponse => new CarViewModel
        {
            Id = carResponse.Id, CarName = carResponse.Name, CarModelNo = carResponse.ModelNo, Colour = carResponse .Colour, FuelType=            carResponse.FuelType
        }).ToList();
    }
```

The data is getting returned to the table correctly but neither the Numeric column of ModelNo nor the Alphabetic columns of name/colour/fuel type are not getting sorted when I click the column header?  Is there something missing in my configurtaion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using WebAPI - this means you will have to write a custom model binder. The facts on the WebAPI case are covered [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-11-29/the_facts_on_using_kendo_ui_with_asp_net_webapi). To see a demo you should check [this code library](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/binding-to-a-web-apicontroller-6cdc432b8326).